# Drag-and-drop files into Linux Mint from virtualized Windows 7

Tags: linux-mint, windows, virtualbox

Linux Mint, newly installed, is on one of my hard drives; Windows 7 is installed on the other HDD.  I anticipate migrating totally to Linux Mint in the future. I have installed a [virtual box into Linux](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and loaded Windows 7 into it.  From Linux, I can see the Linux HDD and the Windows HDD.

I want to drag and drop files from Windows into Linux Mint, and Linux will let me do this when I am dropping Windows files onto the Linux desktop, but it will not let me drop files either directly from the Windows HDD into the virtual box, or drop files from the Linux desktop into the virtual box.

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?  If so, what is the recommended procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not drag and dropped files, but in general ensure that drag-and-drop is set to bi-directional.

Alternatively, add a file share, and use this to move files (This is what I did).